# Count number of trees?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to show that for $n\geq2$, there are exactly $\frac{1}{n}{2n-2 \choose n-1}$ rooted plane trees on $n+1$ vertices, and the root vertex has degree two. Could someone give me hints as to how to show this? Is this related to Catalan numbers?

Comment: Well, how many trees are there on $n$ vertices, where $n\ge1$? (This isn't necessarily a hint, just the first question that pops into my mind.)

Comment: Interesting Note: Perhaps Induction using recurrence relation?

Comment: the inductive step does not really work I think, suppose the inductive hypothesis holds for $n$, I'm not sure what to apply for $n+1$

Comment: Do you already know the fact that the number of rooted plane trees on $n+1$ vertices, without any restriction on the degree of the root, is the Catalan number $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$?

Comment: yes I have seen that proof in the textbook. But I am not sure how to apply that fact in this problem.

Comment: Okay; hang on a few minutes, and I’ll write up an answer pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $a_n$ be the number of rooted plane trees on $n+1$ vertices whose root has degree $2$; you’re trying to show that $a_n$ is the Catalan number $C_{n-1}$. You’ll want the following two facts.

- The Catalan numbers satisfy the recurrence

$$C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}\;.$$

- The number of rooted plane trees on $n+1$ vertices, without any restriction on the degree of the root, is the Catalan number $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$.

Now suppose that $T$ is a rooted plane tree on $n+1$ vertices whose root has degree $2$. If you remove the root, you’re left with two rooted plane trees. If the one on the left has $k$ vertices, the one on the right has $n-k$ vertices.

- What are the possible values for $k$?
- For a given $k$, how many possibilities are there for the left subtree? For the right subtree?
- Now put those pieces together to calculate $a_n$.

Comment: is $k$ valid from $1$ to $n-1$? since there could be one vertex on one of the subtrees, hence the other side has $n-1$ vertices.

Comment: @LeBronJames: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: right now I am doing $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} C_{n}*C_{n-k}$$ but I'm not getting the same results, is this the right approach?

Comment: @LeBronJames: You have the general idea, but the details need quite a bit of work. There are $C_{k-1}$ rooted plane trees with $k$ vertices, so your first factor should by $C_{k-1}$, not $C_n$. Can you see now what the other factor should be?

Comment: sorry, $C_n$ was a typo. so it should be $$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} C_{k-1}*C_{n-k-1}$$

Comment: @LeBronJames: You want $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$, not $\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}$, but otherwise it’s okay. Now let $j=k-1$, so that $k=j+1$, and rewrite the summation in terms of $j$ instead of $k$: $\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\ldots\;$. If you do the translation correctly, everything will fall into place perfectly to give you what you want.

Comment: sorry that was another typo. I think I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @LeBronJames: You’re very welcome. (I suspected that reversing the $k$ and $n$ was just a typo.)